# How to keep a service running on a Docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a simple docker container with my web application installed (Not using docker file).
During the testing I would always run a container using -t -i option and then start the tomcat service inside it by running a shell script.
How when I am moving to production I dont want to use the -t -i option any more and just need my Tomcat service to start and be the only primary service.

I trying pointing the entrypoint to the start up script for starting tomcat but the container terminates after that script finishes.
How do I run a container, start a service and keep that service as the single primary service of the container?

Note: I read some posts about supervisor but not sure if I would need to start building my image from scratch if I go that route? I would prefer not doing that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a Dockerfile that uses an entrypoint pattern, it will look something like this:

(Dockerfile)

```
FROM ubuntu

...Some configuration steps...

add start.sh /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

All you need to do is make sure your `start.sh` script 'hangs' in some way.  Some people like to tail the syslogs, but tailing any file that exists will work.

(start.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

service Your_Service_Or_Whatever start
tail -f /var/log/dmesg
```

Comment: Ok, but if the entrypoint is not run as root and if the sudo command is not installed ?

Comment: You can literally tail any file, even a file you create yourself within the script such as with `touch /tmp/file && tail -f /tmp/file`

Answer (score 4):

A shorter version:

```
FROM ubuntu

...Some configuration steps...

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 1; done"]
```

tested with Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Use `docker --version` to find out your version

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers as default will run according to the configuration in the images `Dockerfile`. If you usually run a container with the `-i` flag, you leave STDIN open allowing you access to the containers entrypoint or it could be a bash shell. To achieve what you want, you can run the container in a detached state passing your commands into docker run directly.

```
docker run -d myapp /opt/catalina/bin/startup.sh
```

This will run the myapp container in a detached state and will run the command passed as the 3rd argument. If the command results in a long lived service, the container will stay active as long as the service is.

[This is explained in detail in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

Comment: Running the container with in detached mode does not help in my case.

I need to run a shell script to get the required service started and as soon as the 
shell script ends, the container exits...

I need to keep the container running using the service thatI start as the primary service

Comment: You will need to run the container in a detached state, the service needs to be run in the foreground to keep it active. From memory you will need something like `$PATH_TO_TOMCAT/startup.sh run`

Comment: Tried that, it starts the service and then the container exists, what seems to be happening is that it treats the shell which I use to start the service as primary service and not the actual service which gets started.

Comment: I would suggest you build you're own container image, then you can define exactly the environment you want/need.